# How do I display an image that is an attachment on an sObject?

Tags: rest-api, attachment, images

I know how to query the image with SOQL, but how can I get the actual file to display on a page? Not sure it makes a difference, but I would be retrieving the image via the REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in the `img` tag's `src` attribute, which contains the base64 encoded image data, like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,BASE_64_ENCODED_DATA" />
```

The REST API will give you the attachment body as base64 data, so you just render it into an `img` tag as above.

Comment: I assume the image caches in the browser like any other image, do you know Pat?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. In fact, it should be cached as part of that HTML page.